# XMLPort Skip empty Tags

Tags: navision, dynamics-nav

I created a XMLport in Dynamics Nav. The problem I have is that empty tags appear in the XML and I need to remove them. I have to do to fix it?

Comment: Please export your XMLPort in text format and post it here. It is quite difficult to figure out what might be wrong from your description.

Comment: You aren't really giving us much to work with here. Please post your XMLPort definition to receive help.

Answer (score 1):

You have to add code to the OnBeforePassVariable trigger of each of your elements and attributes. Just check if the value is empty and skip it.

```
awesomefield - Export::OnBeforePassVariable()
IF awesomefield  = '' THEN
  currXMLport.SKIP;
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use the XMLDoc.transformNodeToObject function with this stylesheet

```
 <xsl:transform xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0" >

  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" />
  <!--Remove alle empty nodes recursively-->
  <xsl:template match="node() | @*">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="node() | @*"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <!--Strip white space between nodes-->
  <xsl:template match="*[normalize-space() = '']"/>
</xsl:transform>
```

Answer (score 0):

By default new elements in an XMLport have their "MinOccurs" and "MaxOccurs" properties set to "Once".  Try setting the "MinOccurs" property for that element to "Zero".  This might work.